# Find angle from North

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sensors

I am trying to write a application that can find the angle from the north (azimuth angle) The phone need to be held up (portrait mode and Landscape mode) the code I pasted below seems to work but sometimes it will give wrong values. Is there a better way of doing this? Also will this work on all phone? I am using Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR for the code below.

```
    int  axisX = 0;
    int axisY=0;


    switch (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
    {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            axisX = SensorManager.AXIS_Z  ;//SensorManager.AXIS_X;
            axisY = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X;
          //  rotation.setText("Rotaion: 0");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            axisX = SensorManager.AXIS_Z  ;//SensorManager.AXIS_X;
            axisY = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X;
           // rotation.setText("Rotaion: 90");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            axisX = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X;
            axisY = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y;
           // rotation.setText("Rotaion: 180");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            axisX =  SensorManager.AXIS_Z;//SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y;
            axisY = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X;;//SensorManager.AXIS_X;
           // rotation.setText("Rotaion: 270");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    //
    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];

    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix,event.values);


    float[] adjustedRotationMatrix = new float[9];

    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, axisX,axisY, adjustedRotationMatrix);

    float[] orientation = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getOrientation(adjustedRotationMatrix, orientation);
    float azimuth =(float) Math.toDegrees( orientation[0])       ;// * FROM_RADS_TO_DEGS;
```

Comment: Can you reliable reproduce incorrect results?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice- it happens at random. I and use the app 10 times without issues then open I start it a 11 time  the angles are wrong